# Display an image for the first item in a Views news list

Tags: views

I want to create a view to display news like in this image:

[image: display news]

The list shows an image only for the first news, the other news only display the title.

Answer (score 3):

[Views nodes split](http://drupal.org/project/views_nodes_split) does exactly this:

> This module allows site administrators or builders to have a different
>   view mode for the first nodes of a view result.

**Source:** Lullabot - [Module Monday: Views Nodes Split](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/module-monday-views-nodes-split)

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty, if you don't mind having all the images loaded in your page, you can use CSS to display the first one and not all the rest, eg:

```
.views-row img {
   display: none;
}

.views-row-first img {
   display: block;
}
```

I would just theme it a bit more specifically on your site, eg, with the views css names and views field names and so forth, the point is that views themes each row specifically, just take a look at the html output.

Comment: Nice trick Jimajamma

Comment: and this way, if you want to get fancy, you can use jQuery and pop open these hidden images when you hover over the other titles :)